# Make BorderPane to look like a Circle

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there any way to make BorderPane to look like a Circle? In my case I would like to hold several Labels into BorderPane which looks like a Circle.

Maybe there is a way to change the borders of the BorderPane?

Comment: I haven't sat down to try this yet (about to start UP1 class) but have you tried using setClip() using a circle as the clipping shape?

Comment: I'm new to JavaFX - I have tried only too basic things of the framework.

Comment: Yeah honestly I'm pretty new to JavaFX as well, but I saw an example at [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-iRc9XkgZ0), specifically look at the last few moments, she uses a shape to clip a pane.

Comment: why (particularly, why a BorderPane)? and how should its contents - at all logical positions - look?

Answer (score 1):

This sort of worked for me

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.getChildren().add(btn);
root.setId("ROOTNODE");
Circle circ = new Circle(100,100,100);
circ.setRadius(60);
root.setClip(circ);
```

CSS:

```
#ROOTNODE {
-fx-background-radius: 30;
-fx-background-color:green;
-fx-border-radius: 30;
-fx-border-width:5;
}
```